# $(12 \cdots n)$ in $S_n$ has $n-1$ inversions. What about the k-th composition?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, symmetric-groups

$\sigma = (12\cdots n)$ has $(n-1)$ inversions because it can be decomposed into transpositions $(1n)\cdots (13)(12)$ and $\sigma^k(i) = i + k \ (mod \ n)$. $\sigma^k$ has $k(n-k)$ inversions but how do we prove it?

Comment: Have you worked out some examples to look for a pattern?

Comment: I think it may be $k(n-k)$ but I don't have a proof of it

Answer (score 2):

This is easily enough answered by looking at what $\sigma$ actually does.

The permutation $\sigma$ is clearly a circular left shift, so for $0\le k<n$ the permutation $\sigma^k$ takes the $n$-tuple $\langle 1,2,\ldots,n\rangle$ to

$$\langle\underbrace{k+1,k+2,\ldots,n}_{n-k\text{ terms}},\underbrace{1,2,\ldots,k}_{k\text{ terms}}\rangle\,.$$

An inversion of $\sigma^k$ is a pair $\langle i,j\rangle$ such that $1\le i<j\le n$ and $\sigma^k(i)>\sigma^k(j)$; this is the case iff $\sigma^k(i)$ is one of the first $n-k$ terms and $\sigma^k(j)$ is one of the last $k$ terms, so there are $k(n-k)$ such pairs, and $\sigma^k$ has $k(n-k)$ inversions.